# Making UIImageView immediately follow finger location without any lag?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

In the `touchesBegin`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` methods, I set the center of the image view:

```
[myImageView setCenter:CGPointMake(location.x, location.y)];
```

The problem is that there's a lag between the quick finger gestures and the image changing its location. I want the image to immediately follow the finger's location without any lag.

I even tried to skip minor location changes in order to keep the image's location concurrent with the finger's location but it wasn't of much help.

```
int diff1=(location.x-oldX);
int diff2=(location.y-oldY);

if (abs(diff1)>=5  || abs(diff2)>=5  || abs(diff1)%5==0  || abs(diff2)%5==0) 
{        
    [myImageView setCenter:CGPointMake(location.x, location.y)];
}
```

Is there a way to improve it in Cocoa Touch? If not then should I switch to `CoreGraphics` or cocos2d etc.?

Help with example code snippets will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. There was a great session on it at WWDC 2010 - you can watch the video [here](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.4092349126.04109539109.4144345617?i=1172435629). The Pan stuff starts at 45 minutes in, but if you've got an hour to spare, watch the whole thing. It's really interesting stuff that will really help you out with gesture recognition.

Comment: Thanks for the info and link however I wasn't looking to _recognize_ gestures rather make my image follow the finger locations as **quickly** as possible. So the problem is image's slow translation.

Comment: If you check out the video, the image tracks well. Have you run Time Profiler over your code to see where the lag is originating?